# The value of adding the ROC graph if the AUC is given

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc

I always see in papers that when they want to show how they classifiers performed, they provide ROC graph and the AUC score. Now as far as I know only the AUC tells how well the classifier performed, so what is the advantage of adding the ROC graph? What can one tell from it?

Comment: This isn't really any different from lots of cases where the data are described numerically in the text, but people like to present the information visually as well.

Answer (score 6):

I usually give the ROC plot but not the AUC: For my applications it is usually clear that either a specific or a sensitive regocognition is needed. The ROC is different for classifiers that are specific but not sensitive vs. sensitive but not specific while the AUC hides this information.

Besides, one can put a whole lot of further information into the plot, e.g. color-coding the thresholds (check whether the classifier is well calibrated if the primary output is posterior probability), model stability (after resampling validation), or confidence regions for a chosen classifier (if one chooses a threshold). Finally, you can even put "extented" measures of sensitivity and specificity which do not require the thresholding @FrankHarrell fights against, e.g. it is possible to extend the concept of sensitivity and specificity and the concept behind Brier's score to yield such measures.

Comment: Is there something about probabilistic decision making that doesn't work in your situation?

Comment: @FrankHarrell: Well, yes: communication. I spend quite a lot of my working time doing translations: physicist <-> chemist (<-> chemometrician) <-> statistician <-> medical doctor, and I find the art of doing this well has a lot to do with allowing simplifications and finding compromises (and trying to avoid to gross misconceptions). I tackle the "don't throw away information" problem by  sneaking in continuous measures (as chemist I prefer MSE/RMSE) which are well (or at least better) behaved, but their names and purpose are familiar.

Comment: I feel that probabilities can work well if communication is careful or the problem involves sports or card playing.

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen a single example where the graph changes our actions or the way we think.  I think the ink:information ratio in an ROC graph is enormous.  But the worst thing about it is that it tempts us to try to select a cutoff for the predicted risk, which is arbitrary, and inconsistent with optimum decision making.

Beware of the word *classifier* which implies discarding continuous information.

Comment: Temptation for a cutoff is a point, but OTOH giving the ROC IMHO is already much better than reporting sensitivity and specificity at some arbitrary default cutpoint without any further information.

Comment: Only if sensitivity and specificity are helpful.  I find them not to be.  If we were regressing age on blood pressure we'd never create an ROC curve.  Why we do it when $Y$ is binary is beyond me.

Comment: @FrankHarrell regression doesn't help when you need to make a *decision*, rather than a prediction. At some point you need to define a threshold. You can't treat a patient for 70%. In those settings, ROC curves provide a valuable summary of the model at different operating settings (in part due to the fact that ROC curves are understood by many). That said, I agree on the high ink:information ratio.

Comment: I have to disagree [and medical diagnosis is one of my main areas of research].  There are only two situations I can think of where your reasoning applies: (1) when the analyst is the possessor of the utility function (highly unusual) or (2) when decisions must be made instantly without the time to assess utilities.  Not only are probabilities the optimum inputs to true decision makers, they allow one to make no decision, when more data are needed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I totally agree that lots of valuable information are lost with the dichotomization. As chemist, my primary philosophical concept of the world is quantitative (substances come at concentrations). So qualitative analysis ("native chemical" version of classification) is the result of comparing a primarily quantitative result to a threshold. However, there are situations which are more basically grouped than continuous. Few people are 20% pregnant... And even in some fundametally continuous situations it just doesn't make sense to cry over the threshold: (...)

Comment: (...) If there is a legal threshold for Pb in drinking water, that's what I have to use. Note that it won't keep me from reporting the quantitative estimate in addition. I agree that the blood pressure is yet different in that there is no external need to dichotomize. Note also that in my legislation reporting continuous scores and normal ranges would be the way to go for clinical diagnostics: only medical doctors are allowed to convert those into the actual diagnosis (= dichotomize).

Comment: The only time I have seen thresholds be necessary is when forced by law.  Even then it's not optimal.  There would be less cheating on federal income tax if taxes were continuously graduated instead of using tax brackets.  Normal ranges are not that useful in decision making because they come only from normals.

Answer (score 2):

The ROC curve is the specificity/sensitivity plot; the AUC is the Area Under Curve. 
To be brief, the ROC curve can be interesting because it allows comparison of the sensitivity/specificity behaviour of the model. More simply:

$ROC = (x,y) \in R^2 \Rightarrow AUC = z$ but $AUC = z \nRightarrow ROC = (x,y) \in R^2$

Comment: I still don't get it. What could one use the ROC graph for if he only needs the AUC to really evaluate the performance?

Answer (score 2):

There is great value in showing the entire ROC esp. when comparing two different classifiers, as it helps us to see whether different curves cross each other. One is not superior to the other, *overall*, if they cross - see the Figure 3 (screenshot shown below) from

Seong Ho Park, J. M. G. C.-H. J. (2004). Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve: Practical Review for Radiologists. Korean Journal of Radiology, 5(1), 11–18.
[image: Crossing ROC curves from Park et al., 2004]

In our own study, we noticed this behaviour for biomarkers that have similar performance, and partial AUCs can be studied to demonstrate their utility for particular applications e.g. in high specificity regions for early detection of Alzheimer's disease.

Citation: Raamana, P. R., Weiner, M. W., Wang, L., & Beg, M. F. (2015). Thickness network features for prognostic applications in dementia. Neurobiology of Aging, 36, S91–S102.

[image: Comparison of ROCs from different methods]

Hope that helps make the case for presenting the ROC always.